# How to Modify ignoreBackdropClick Dynamically for Modal Opened with BsModalRef in ngx-bootstrap?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on an Angular application that uses the ngx-bootstrap library for modals. Currently, I have a scenario where I want to dynamically modify the ignoreBackdropClick property of a modal that was opened using BsModalRef. Specifically, I want to set ignoreBackdropClick to true when an HTTP call is in progress within the modal and revert it to false once the HTTP call completes.

Here's a brief overview of my current code structure:

```
<ng-template #stateChangeDialog>
 content...
</ng-template>

export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChild('stateChangeDialog', { static: true }) public stateChangeDialog: any;
  private stateChangeDialogRef: BsModalRef;

  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  openModal() {
    this.stateChangeDialogRef = this.modalService.show(this.stateChangeDialog);
  }

  // Other methods...
}
```

I want to achieve the following behavior:

When a button is clicked within the stateChangeDialog modal, an HTTP call is initiated.
While the HTTP call is in progress, I want to set ignoreBackdropClick to true so that the user cannot close the modal.
Once the HTTP call is complete, I want to revert ignoreBackdropClick back to false so that the user can close the modal again.
My question is: How can I achieve this dynamic modification of the ignoreBackdropClick property based on the HTTP call status within the modal? Can I achieve this using the stateChangeDialogRef that I have, or is there an alternative approach I should consider?

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!